# adding text to titlebar in all root windows

Tags: users, mate-desktop, window-management, window-title

When a window is opended with root priveleges, I want to display some text in the titlebar to inform the user that he/she is root in that particular instance.

I'm currently using the MATE desktop manager but could consider switching to KDE if there is a viable option.

I've tried the compiz plugin titlebarinfo and its not exactly to my liking because I can't change the text string displayed. I tried recompiling the plugin to simply change the text but I can't get it to compile on Fedora for several reasons.

Comment: That's a good question, but please tell us what those “several reasons” are that you couldn't get it to compile (copy-paste the commands you ran and the full traces). Also please fix your `Shift` and `'` keys.